# How might I 'hold' an iteration value based on an if condition, and once satisfied, continue the logical sequencing?

Tags: python, for-loop, iteration

I need to formulate an iteration sequence that follows the output pattern below:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
6
7
8
```

However my attempts insofar are yielding an output that returns back to iteration, rather than returning to a logical sequencing:

```
for i in range(10):
    if i==7:
        i=i-1
    print(i)

0
1
2
3
4
5
6
6
8
9
```

I feel as though I am overlooking something incredibly simple, or something that is an obvious syntactical error?!

**Edit -
Firstly, thanks for taking the time to assist in this issue.
I did try all the following, unfortunately the general principle is not compatible with the program at hand.

So, to elaborate:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

sDate=date(2021,7,24)
eDate=date(2016,1, 1)
delta=sDate-eDate

leapCycle=4
for i in range(delta.days):
    date=sDate-timedelta(days=i)
    year=date.year
    month=date.month
    day=date.day
    leap_year=(year%leapCycle)
    if day==28 and month==2 and leap_year==0:
        temp=i-1
        print(temp,date)
    print(i,date)
```

and this is outputting

```
...
510 2020-03-01
511 2020-02-29
511 2020-02-28
512 2020-02-28
513 2020-02-27
...
1971 2016-03-01
1972 2016-02-29
1972 2016-02-28
1973 2016-02-28
1974 2016-02-27
...
```

As you can see, i is 'held' as required however now the date is reiterated (making the 'holding' obsolete).  Please also note, that i is being used to cycle through data sets that correspond to the associated iterate number so it is important that i,date,and data do what is needed.

Thanks again

Comment: How many repeats should there be? Does it always only repeat once, or could it be more than that?

Comment: I have simplified the code into a generic format, like a strategy, in order to gain the appropriate principle, with which I will then apply that principle to the program/project as a whole - since the 'i' iteration is being used as a trigger for a rather complex array of dependent events - so to answer you question, the for loop does not need to repeat, but this 'holding' of 'i', needs only occur for one step at time, but there are many occurrences that it must be held for one step (although it will be handy to know how to do it for as many as I like in future - think trap hi-hats...)

Comment: From what you say, at least one of the answers you have aleady been given should solve your problem - in which case, please accept the one you found most useful by clicking the tick mark next to it. Otherwise, please explain in more detail why the answers aren't suitable, and [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69266415/edit) accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

This is simpler

```
for i in range(9):
    if i==7:
        temp=i-1
        print(temp)
    print(i)
```

Your code is is causing you to over write your `i` value.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try something like this:

```
def print_with_condition(limit, condition):
    for i in range(limit):
        if condition(i):
            print(i)
        print(i)


print_with_condition(9, lambda x: x == 6)
```

The above code would produce this result:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
6
7
8
```

## EDIT 1

If you want a simpler approach:

```
for i in range(10):
    if i != 9:
        if i == 6:
            print(i)
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

The last number is not taken into account. You need to write **for i in range(9)**

Answer (score 0):

Just few lines of change in your code (added `print` inside `if` block) gives the desired results:

```
for i in range(9):
    if (i == 7):
       print (i-1)
    print (i)
```

OR if you still want to iterate until `range(10)`, this is the code:

```
for i in range(10):
    if (i >= 7):
        print (i-1)
    else:
        print (i)
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
6
7
8
```

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop , when i=7 we temporarily make i=6 and print it. But the for loop had run till the i=7 state , hence for the next iteration 'i' will be 8 due to for loop behavior, which explains your output. You can achieve your desired output , by printing i-1 for every iteration from when i=7.

Code:

```
for i in range(10):
    if i>=7:
        print(i-1)
    else:
        print(i)
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
6
7
8
```